# subsetting data to first occurrence in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset the data so it only preserves the first occurrence of a variable. I'm looking at a panel data that traces the career of workers, and I'm trying to subset the data so that it only shows until each person became Boss.

```
id  year    name    job    job2
1   1990    Bon     Manager 0
1   1991    Bon     Manager 0
1   1992    Bon     Manager 0
1   1993    Bon     Boss    1
1   1994    Bon     Manager 0
2   1990    Jane    Manager 0
2   1991    Jane    Boss    1
2   1992    Jane    Manager 0
2   1993    Jane    Boss    1
```

So I would want the data to look like:

```
id  year    name    job   job2
1   1990    Bon     Manager 0
1   1991    Bon     Manager 0
1   1992    Bon     Manager 0
1   1993    Bon     Boss    1
2   1990    Jane    Manager 0
2   1991    Jane    Boss    1
```

This seems like basic censoring but for the sake of my analysis this is crucial..! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base solution:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  by(dat,dat$name,function(x) {
    if ("Boss" %in% x$job) x[1:min(which(x$job=="Boss")),]
  })
)

#       id year name     job job2
#Bon.1   1 1990  Bon Manager    0
#Bon.2   1 1991  Bon Manager    0
#Bon.3   1 1992  Bon Manager    0
#Bon.4   1 1993  Bon    Boss    1
#Jane.6  2 1990 Jane Manager    0
#Jane.7  2 1991 Jane    Boss    1
```

An alternative base solution:

```
dat$keep <- with(dat, 
             ave(job=="Boss",name,FUN=function(x) if(1 %in% x) cumsum(x) else 2) 
            )
with(dat, dat[keep==0 | (job=="Boss" & keep==1),] )

#  id year name     job job2 keep
#1  1 1990  Bon Manager    0    0
#2  1 1991  Bon Manager    0    0
#3  1 1992  Bon Manager    0    0
#4  1 1993  Bon    Boss    1    1
#6  2 1990 Jane Manager    0    0
#7  2 1991 Jane    Boss    1    1
```

And a `data.table` solution:

```
dat <- as.data.table(dat)
dat[,if("Boss" %in% job) .SD[1:min(which(job=="Boss"))],by=name]

#   name id year     job job2
#1:  Bon  1 1990 Manager    0
#2:  Bon  1 1991 Manager    0
#3:  Bon  1 1992 Manager    0
#4:  Bon  1 1993    Boss    1
#5: Jane  2 1990 Manager    0
#6: Jane  2 1991    Boss    1
```

Comment: Another data.table way: `dat[dat[, .I[seq_len(which(job2 == 1L)[1L])], by=id]$V1]`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a dplyr solution that uses two useful [window functions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html) `lag()` and `cumall()`:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
id  year    name    job    job2
1   1990    Bon     Manager 0
1   1991    Bon     Manager 0
1   1992    Bon     Manager 0
1   1993    Bon     Boss    1
1   1994    Bon     Manager 0
2   1990    Jane    Manager 0
2   1991    Jane    Boss    1
2   1992    Jane    Manager 0
2   1993    Jane    Boss    1
", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

# Use mutate to see the values of the new variables
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(last_job = lag(job, default = ""), cumall(last_job != "Boss"))

# Use filter to see the results
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cumall(lag(job, default = "") != "Boss"))
```

We use `lag()` to figure out what job each person had in the previous year, and then use `cumall()` to keep all rows up to the first instance of "Boss".  If the data wasn't already sorted by year, you could use `lag(job, order_by = year)` to make sure `lag()` used the value of year, rather than the row order, to determine which was "last" year.

Answer (score 2):

The library 'sqldf' could do the work.

```
library(sqldf)
miny <- sqldf("select id, min(year) as year from df where job='Boss' group by id")
sqldf("select df.* from df join miny on (df.id=miny.id and df.year<=miny.year)")
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is stored in a data frame called `df`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(.data=df, .variables=c("name"), .fun=function(x) {
  i <- which(x$job == "Boss")[1]
  if (!is.na(i)) x[1:i, ] # omit lifelong managers 
})
#   id year name     job job2
# 1  1 1990  Bon Manager    0
# 2  1 1991  Bon Manager    0
# 3  1 1992  Bon Manager    0
# 4  1 1993  Bon    Boss    1
# 5  2 1990 Jane Manager    0
# 6  2 1991 Jane    Boss    1
```